# Writing stored procedures in snowflake

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to write a stored procedure in snowflake SQL. Here is what I'm trying to do

Step 1: Write a QUERY1 to get a set of information say (date, serial number).

Step 2: For each Row values in the results I got in the above step, I need to execute QUERY2, so that I can get more details for date 1 and serial number1 add it to a result table, and then get information about date 2 and serial number 2 and so on.

Meaning I need to iterate through each row line in query 1  and executive query 2 and put it in a table to get a result.

How can I implement this using stored procedure? I don't have a write access and I am able to use CTE.

Comment: It will be very slow inserting one row at a time. I would try to find a way to do steps 1 and 2 in SQL. Please share more details about the processing along with sample input and output tables. If the requirements aren't possible or practicable in SQL, there are ways to buffer rows to avoid single-row insertions.

Comment: You should be able to do a set-based query with a join to get that additional information, and if you ultimately need to get this data to be persisted in a table, you can do an insert with select.  Like Greg said above, with Snowflake you want to avoid row-based processing if possible.

Comment: Have you tried to write anything using Snowflake Scripting? At which point, do you need help?